# How to get Speed limit value using OSM Android

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am using OSRMRoadManager
i am getting the road through OSRMRoadManager.getRoads:http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/105.8680712896,20.9947322000;105.8922453000,21.0393411000?alternatives=true&overview=full&steps=true

is there any API through which i can get maximum speed limits between two node pints ?